# Custom checkbox bootstrap toggle switch with text

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-switch

I'm trying to achieve like below image but not get any result yet. I need a **switch button with different text** like Yes/No, Automatic/Custom, Check/Uncheck. I tried but not get same as below image.

View Demo Code :  http://discountwicedeals.com/toggle.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `jQuery`.

Some awesome plugins can be found (example and download) here: https://simontabor.com/labs/toggles/.

If you like to search something else, search 'jQuery toggle buttons' on **Google**. I recommend to have a source with `HTML` and `jQuery` code. Otherwise you need to modify the code, which *could* be pain.

Related to the first link I gave you: https://simontabor.com/labs/toggles/, see this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-toggles. At **step 3** you can customize your toggle button.

Look at this:

```
// With options (defaults shown below) 
$('.toggle').toggles({
  drag: true, // allow dragging the toggle between positions 
  click: true, // allow clicking on the toggle 
  text: {
    on: 'ON', // text for the ON position 
    off: 'OFF' // and off 
  },
  on: true, // is the toggle ON on init 
  animate: 250, // animation time (ms) 
  easing: 'swing', // animation transition easing function 
  checkbox: null, // the checkbox to toggle (for use in forms) 
  clicker: null, // element that can be clicked on to toggle. removes binding from the toggle itself (use nesting) 
  width: 50, // width used if not set in css 
  height: 20, // height if not set in css 
  type: 'compact' // if this is set to 'select' then the select style toggle will be used 
});
```

The piece of code which is called `text:` means you can set text for toggle ON and OFF. That's exactly what you need.

**At last:**

If you really, really want to have the same design as your link: you can get the same design by copy the script, try to make a total different page in your home directory and copy paste the html and javascript by pressing `F12`. You'll see you'll get the same design. From there on you can try to implement the design with the needed scripts to get the same design.

Comment: Thanks but I already search all that but didn't get same toggle button. I need toggle button with custom checkbox as like image see the image.

Comment: Within the link i just gave you you can have custom text. So perhaps you didnt your homework good enough. The toggle button with custom code is called 'Custom Text' 3rd on the right side. code: `$('.toggle').toggles({text:{on:'HI',off:'BYE'}});`

Comment: This is related to the link at simontabor i gave you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-toggles. This is a tutorial on how to use some of the toggle buttons.

Comment: I already do all that but can't get same design [check link](http://discountwicedeals.com/toggle.html)

Comment: You can get the same design by copy the script, try to make a total different page in your home directory and copy paste the html and javascript by pressing `F12`. You'll see you'll get the same design.

Comment: Otherwise you might consider to get another design, like the link i gave you in my answer. I'll edit my answer with text above.

Comment: Not satisfied with your answer

Comment: Well, I gave you two options: OR copy paste the script from the link you gave me to get the same result, OR get another toggle button which I gave an example with links. I can't change that man, that's up to you. There is not really another solution, unless you post your scripts so 'we' can modify it.